# how to start process minimized on windows with factor

Tags: windows, factor-lang

I have an executable which I call from my factor program (with ) a few times in a second. And it always pops up and becomes the active window even if the listener is in the background. How could I start it minimized or just not as the active window? Is there a paramater of the 'process' that can be set this way?

Comment: Is this a GUI app or a console app? How are your creating the new process?

Comment: Console, with <process> and launch it with <process-reader>. I found a CREATE_NO_WINDOW switch at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and could hard-code into io.launcher.windows to not create the window. For normal handling I should expand the process tuple and use it in io.launcher.windows. I guess

Comment: CREATE_NO_WINDOW is what you want. That's where my question was leading.